# How do I resolve printing errors caused by R Metadata?

Tags: r, printing, metadata

my printer (Kyocera Ecosys P2035d) prints only the following sentence:
"PK§&$/R!!Metadata/Job_PT.xml"

I reinstalled the printer, tried this [procedure](https://www.papercut.com/kb/Main/CapturingAWindowsSpoolFile), but nothing works and I don't know how to fix this in R or what causes the problem.
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

still haven't figured out the problem with R. However, using the [KX universal driver](https://www.kyoceradocumentsolutions.eu/en/support/downloads.name-L2V1L2VuL3ByaW50ZXJzL0VDT1NZU1AyMDM1RA==.html) does the job.